# How to run git commands from chrome extension

Tags: git, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am working on an extension which needs to clone a repository on some action. Is there a way I can achieve that? I see google provide [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) but I am not sure if I can clone repositories and also show progress of clone using extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to write a separate utility (or find an existing one) that runs git and sets the necessary progress hooks or just redirects stdout and sends it via native messaging to your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm: can that utility be a python script? Also, can you provide link to any sample apps?

Comment: Yes it can. A sample is included in the official documentation.

Comment: I have been using [textern](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textern/) extension that runs a configurable text editor to edit TEXTAREAs. The native part is written in Python. See the code an installation instructions at https://github.com/jlebon/textern.